# Check box add input to text box total selection and total cost of selection

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
<script>
var itemsAdded = Array();

function moveNumbers(text) { 
var i = itemsAdded.indexOf(text)
if ( i >= 0) { 
   itemsAdded.splice(i,1); 
 } else {
   itemsAdded.push(text);
 }
 document.getElementById("result").value=itemsAdded.join(" "); 
 } 
 $(function() {
 for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
 console.log(i);
 $("body").append("<input type='checkbox' name='add' value='" + i + "'   onclick='moveNumbers(this.value)'/>          Checkbox" + i + "<br/>");
 }
 });



 </script>
 <textarea id="result" cols="12" rows="6" readonly>
 </textarea>
 <tr>

 <?php
 $path = "photos/";
 $dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open folder");
 echo "<table height='500px'width='800px'align='center'border='1'>";
 echo "<tr>";
 while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir_handle))) {

 if($file == "index.php")
 continue;
 if($file == ".")
 continue;
 if($file == "..")
 continue;
 {
echo ($x % 6 == 0) ? "</tr><tr>" : "";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='add' value='$file' onclick='moveNumbers(this.value)'>
<img src='photos/$file'alt='$file' style='height:auto;width:85%;'alt='$file'>
<br>
$file
</td>";
$x++;
}
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
closedir($dir_handle);
?>
```

Hi all, I have managed to figure out how to add check box input to text box to list items selected.Thanks to those who help me on here (Fred and Joe). Now I need to add another text box to add up how many total items selected and another one to add total cost of all items selected. `E.G. Check box checked -> Add to list text box (this bit already works) -> Add total items listed to text box -> Add total cost of all items selected (each image costs say $10 each)` I have had a go but the script was so messy I thought I would just post the original starting one. To much to ask you think? Cheers.

Comment: `user1829346` This could do with quite a bit of cleaning up. Why are you looping by 10, I don't think that's clear in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does everything that you've asked for (note I've also cleaned the code up a lot, I'd encourage you to check out more about jQuery as you seemed to be doing things with JavaScript that you might as well do with jQuery.

- Every time you click a checkbox, it runs the function `calculateCheckout()`, this finds all of the checked checkboxed, and calculates the total number selected, and the total price.
- I'm storing the price in an attribute called `data-price`. In my JSFiddle it just takes the incremental value and multiplies it by two, but in a working example it should be anything numeric.
- The solution will now check the entire body for any input with the class `product-check`. As long as your checkboxes can have this class then this solution will work. I've added an example product to give you an idea of how you should use the checkboxes correctly.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zcra9/9/)

**JS**

```
var itemsAdded = [];

function calculateCheckout() { 
  var checked_boxes = $("input.product-check:checked"); // Find all checked checkboxes
  var items_total = 0;
  $("#x-names").val(""); // Reset the list of names
  checked_boxes.each(function() { // Loop through all of our checkboxes
    // Add the name (taken from the checkbox data-name attribute) to the list of names
    $("#x-names").val($("#x-names").val() + " " + $(this).attr("data-name")); 
    items_total += parseFloat($(this).val()); // Iterate our total price by taking the checkbox value
  });    
  // Record the total checkbox length
  $("#x-length").val(checked_boxes.length); 
  $("#x-total").val(items_total);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Set an event to call calculateCheckout every time an element with class .check-move is clicked. 
  // See the jQuery 'on' function for more info
  $("body").on("click", "input.product-check", calculateCheckout);
  for (i=1;i<5;i++) {
    $("#checkboxes").append("<input type='checkbox' class='product-check' value='"+(i * 2 )+"' data-name='"+i+"' /> Checkbox" + i + "<br />");
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="checkboxes"></div>
<h1>Selected Products</h1>
<textarea id="x-names"></textarea>
<h1>Total Selected</h1>
<input id="x-length" />
<h1>Total Price</h1>
<input id="x-total" />
<input type="checkbox" value="745" data-name="samgs4" class="product-check" /> Galaxy S4
```

Comment: OK Cheers, I'll do my best. At the moment when a check box is checked it adds the items name which are image files to a text box (IMG_1234.jpg). What I am trying to add to it is  another text box that displays the total items checked (1) then another text box that displays the total cost of all items checked (10). Items might be say to the value of $10 each. E.G. Text box 1 = Image name, Text box 2 = Total images selected, Text box 3 = Total cost of images selected.

Comment: OK get you, I'll whip something up quickly - BTW, why textareas?

Comment: I'm adding to a form then submitting via submit button to email the form. It's like an order form for purchasing photos. Other fields I have include Name, Email Addy, Order Ref ID and now trying to add how many photos selected etc...

Comment: Nice job, but the issue I had last time is that the PHP part of the code scans the directory full of images then adds its own check boxes next to images displayed. Basically the PHP adds the check boxes on the fly. Hence there are no hard coded check boxes. So I have problems with check boxes with allocated type of ID's if that makes sense?

Comment: You'll just need to change the selector so that it picks up the event. Where are your checkboxes being generated, and can you just add a class to them?

Comment: I've updated this to have some useful comments and solve your issue (provided you can add a class to your checkboxes, otherwise, just replace the references to `input.product-check` with `input[type='checkbox']` e.g. - Please upvote and select as the right answer if you're happy

Comment: does there need to be an onclick= at all?

Comment: this is what I have changed on my PHP check box  `echo "<td><input type='checkbox' class='product-check' value='10' data-name='$file'>`

Comment: No, that's handled with the jQuery `$("body").on("click", "input.product-check", calculateCheckout);` - to break it down, we set a click event on the body. Because the checkboxes don't exist when we load the page, we can't attach the event to them, and so delegate the event to the body. The second parameter tells our body to run the function only if we **also** clicked in a class `product-check` at the same time. See 'delegated events' [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Yep got it I'll keep playing around with it I'm not to far off putting it together in my head

Comment: No problem :) - keep learning and always play around, jQuery is very powerful